# STL: Create vector<T*> from vector<T> when T(const T&) is deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

How can I create **`std::vector<T*>`** from **`std::vector<T>`** when copy constructor **`T(const T&)`** is deleted?

Why do I need this?
- Our threading(**tbb**) functor requires `vector` of `T*`.

```
// sample code
std::vector<T> vt;
std::vector<T*> vtp;

for (...)
{
    T a;
    a.build(args...); // 'build()' rebuilds the point tree

    vt.push_back(a);
}

// store T pointer in vtp
for (auto i = vt.begin(); i != vt.end(); i++)
    vtp.emplace_back(&*i); // error: use of deleted function 'T::T(const T&)'
```

Since I'm creating `T` object `a` in a loop so I can't(uniquely) store `a*` directly into `vtp` as it would be overwritten on the same address. I'm using **C++11** and **GCC4.8**.

I've an alternative solution:

```
T t_a1, t_a2, t_a3, t_a4;
vtp = {&t_a1, &t_a2, &t_a3, &t_a4};

for (...)
{
    (vtp[pageIdx])->build(args...); // pageIdx is block index in current range block
}
```

In this approach I need to build certain number of the trees in advance. Although, I can easily calculate the number of trees by getting the number of blocks in the range. But I want to avoid manual creation of the tree in advance and I'm not sure whether it would be efficient.

Comment: Can’t you just take addresses to the first vector elements and store them in 2nd vector of pointers and make sure 1st vector doesn’t cease to exist before second vector?

Comment: How will the push_back work without copying?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/KSJAX78434). The code you show should work. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. Prepare a [mcve]

Comment: If `T` is not copyable, `vt.push_back(a);` would be failing. You wouldn't be able to populate `vt` vector in the first place; at least, not in the way you are showing. Once again, [mcve] would help clarify matters.